# How to give height from bottom instead of top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, cgrectmake

I have textview to display some content. I know `CGRectMake(10,50,100,100)`. The 50 is reduce from Top Margin. I need to reduce the from bottom of 50. Where to change the code?

Comment: Use autolayout, if you wish that yours app got in AppStore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the `textView` while leaving atleast 50px from the bottom, do:

```
CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 150, 100, 100)
```

---

`self.view.frame.size.height` will give you the height of `self.view`.

Answer (score 0):

Just reduce the height factor
       CGRectMake(10,50,100,50)